# initial JSF1.1 bean after request parameters are set

Tags: jsf

I need to perform some initialization of a JSF1.1 bean after all URL request parameters are set.  Is there a good way to do so?  For example, if the manage-bean is setup in faces-config like below, I need to perform some initialization after all there param (Param1, 2, 3) are set.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>someBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.arch.SomeBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>param1</property-name>
        <value>#{param.param1}</value>
    </managed-property>  

    <managed-property>
        <property-name>param2</property-name>
        <value>#{param.param2}</value>
    </managed-property>  

    <managed-property>
        <property-name>param3</property-name>
        <value>#{param.param3}</value>
    </managed-property>  

</managed-bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you would use a `@PostConstruct` annotated method for this, but the support for `@PostConstruct` is only available since JSF 1.2.

Your best bet is to lazily execute it in the setter method of the managed property. E.g.

```
public void setParam3(String param3) {
    boolean wasNull = this.param3 == null;
    this.param3 = param3;

    if (wasNull) {
        init();
    }
}
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF - Passing GET parameters to backing bean](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#PassingGETParametersFromJSFToBackingBeans)

---

Alternatively, just upgrade to JSF 1.2. JSF 1.1 is fully forward compatible with JSF 1.2 without any changes in the code (expect of code where in you're incorrectly assuming a JSF 1.1 specific bug to be correct behavior).

Comment: Do you know if setters of <managed-property> are always executed sequentially? Meaning, the first managed-property will always be executed first and the last will always executed last?

Comment: I can't tell that from top of head. I wouldn't rely on that either without looking at JSF 1.1 impl source code. It's perhaps easier to manually fiddle with `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()` in the constructor. If you can, I'd upgrade to JSF 1.2. as soon as possible. JSF 1.1 is cluttered of bugs in core and performance areas.

Comment: Thank you once again.  Working on moving toward 2.0.  But it is one of those thing that management/operation does not really want to give too much time for.  So, it is going very slowing.

Comment: You're welcome. JSF 2.x is much better, but requires many more migration effort. JSF 1.1 to 1.2 should really be just a matter of changing JARs and editing faces-config.xml root declaration.